# Image.FromStream: Parameter not valid

Tags: .net, imaging

I am trying to create an image from a byte array.  The byte array is created by a fingerprint scanner (cf CaptureFrame method).  fwidth is 256 and fheight is 255.

When I run the code below, I get

> System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.

```
Dim fWidth As Short
Dim fHeight As Short

DFRProxy.DFRProxy.GetImageDimensions(fWidth, fHeight)

Dim imgBufLength As Integer = CInt(fWidth) * fHeight

Dim finger(imgBufLength) As Byte

Dim startCap As Short = DFRProxy.DFRProxy.StartCapture(0)

Dim capFrame As Short = DFRProxy.DFRProxy.CaptureFrame(0, finger, 0)


Using ms As New IO.MemoryStream(finger)
    thisImage = Image.FromStream(ms)
End Using
```

The error occurs at line

```
thisImage = Image.FromStream(ms)
```

The byte array has 65280 elements.  I have reviewed several StackOverflow postings that are similar to this, but nothing has worked.  I have tried setting the `useEmbeddedColorManagement` and `validateImageData` parameters for the FromStream method to False and True, but this does not solve the problem.

Do you have any suggestions on how to correct the `ArgumentException`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

FromStream is expecting data in one of these formats:

> Managed GDI+ has built-in encoders and decoders that support the following file types:
>
> - BMP
> - GIF
> - JPEG
> - PNG
> - TIFF

Your byte array I suspect is not in these and does not have the metadata or compression information each of these formats expects.

What you want to do is create a Bitmap object and read through each pixel in the byte array, calling SetPixel in the bitmap for the appropriate pixel.  You'll end up with a Bitmap (which is an Image) that has the pixels you want.

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks.  It's a grayscale image.  When I use the SetPixel method, how do I convert the grayscale value (0-255) to a system color?

Comment: If value is v, new Color(v,v,v) should do the trick (creates a color with equal RGB components, which should be gray)

Comment: That did it.  Thanks for the excellent answer.  It's been driving me crazy for hours.

Comment: hey @blueshift is there anyway you can share your code here?

Answer (score 5):

Try the following:

```
TypeConverter tc = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Bitmap));
Bitmap bitmap1 = (Bitmap)tc.ConvertFrom(byteArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to >ggsmartboy answer for VB.NET:

On top of module/class/form

```
Imports system.componentmodel
```

In the code

```
Dim ba As New Byte() 'Make sure you set the byte array to something
Dim tc As TypeConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(GetType(Bitmap))
Dim bmp As Bitmap = tc.ConvertFrom(ba)
```

And subsequently:

```
PictureBox1.Image = bmp
```

Cheers