# How to retrieve image from database and paste to picturebox?

Tags: c#

Any help is much appreciated, guys. I tried using the dataset and other solutions to no avail. The error I keep getting is "Parameter is not valid." My code is this:

```
try
        {
            conn.Open();

            MySqlCommand comm = new MySqlCommand("SELECT lastname, firstname, picture FROM casestudyprofile WHERE caseid = " + id, conn);
            MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(comm);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            adp.Fill(dt);

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {

                lblname.Text = dt.Rows[0]["firstname"].ToString() + " " + dt.Rows[0]["lastname"].ToString();


                pbox2.Image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream((byte[])dt.Rows[0]["picture"]));

            }

            conn.Close();
        }
```

Comment: The error seems triggered from byte array stored in `MemoryStream` here: `Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream((byte[])dt.Rows[0]["picture"]))`. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712557/image-fromstream-parameter-not-valid for similar problem.

Comment: Your code is fine. You should check if the `picture` column has data of not (it's probably a `blob` column, I guess).

Comment: @BobDust Yes it's a blob column. I'll double check again. Thanks.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Based on ur link, I tried to use Bitmap like this:

`pbox2.Image = new Bitmap(new MemoryStream((byte[])dt.Rows[0]["picture"]));`

Sadly, still the same error. The picture in database is PNG, data type BLOB.